# Increase cell value in range by one on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook 40 sheets, 30 of them have the same excel table set up. I need a macro which will increment by 1 all cells within the 30 sheets in the table range on the column "Months Billed". I have tried the following which worked on one sheet - but unsure how to have the same work across multiple sheets - I also don't need the message box:

```
    Sub MonthIncrease()
     Dim r1 As Range
     Dim cell As Range
      Set r1 = Sheets("Customer 1").Range("Customer1[Months Billed]")
    For Each cell In r1
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
           If cell.Value > 0 Then
           cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " does not have a number"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Next
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that those 30 out of 40 sheets have names like "Customer 1", "Customer 2", ...

in this case go like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub MonthIncrease()
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 30
    With Sheets("Customer " & i).Range("Customer1[Months Billed]")
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
           If cell.Value > 0 Then cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
        Next cell
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

where I also took off the `Exit Sub` statement along with the `MsgBox` one

should those numbers you're searching for be the result of formulas then just change

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
```

into

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MonthIncrease()
Dim r1 As Range, cell As Range, i As Integer

For i = 1 To 30
    Set r1 = Sheets(i).Range("Customer1[Months Billed]")

    For Each cell In r1
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
           If cell.Value > 0 Then
           cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address(0, 0) & " does not have a number"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
Next i

End Sub
```